# python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pyobjc

I have installed 'matplotlib' but still, it gives the error:

> No module name 'matplotlib'

These are the list that has been installed :

> altgraph                               0.10.2
>   backports-abc                          0.5
>   bdist-mpkg                             0.5.0
>   bonjour-py                             0.3
>   futures                                3.2.0
>   macholib                               1.5.1
>   matplotlib                             1.3.1
>   modulegraph                            0.10.4
>   nose                                   1.3.7
>   numpy                                  1.8.0rc1
>   pip                                    10.0.1
>   py2app                                 0.7.3
>   pyobjc-core                            2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-Accounts              2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-AddressBook           2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit        2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC       2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-Automator             2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork             2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-Cocoa                 2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-Collaboration         2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-CoreData              2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation          2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-CoreText              2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices    2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-EventKit              2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling     2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-FSEvents              2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit        2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins      2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage        2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping 2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices        2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-Message               2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory         2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes       2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-PubSub                2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-QTKit                 2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-Quartz                2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver           2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge       2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-SearchKit             2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement     2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-Social                2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-SyncServices          2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration   2.5.1
>   pyobjc-framework-WebKit                2.5.1
>   pyOpenSSL                              0.13.1
>   pyparsing                              2.0.1
>   python-dateutil                        1.5
>   pytz                                   2013.7
>   scipy                                  0.13.0b1
>   setuptools                             18.5
>   singledispatch                         3.4.0.3 
>   six                                    1.4.1
>   tornado                                5.0.2
>   xattr                                  0.6.4

I have done a lot of searching but could not find any solution.

Comment: which python version?

Comment: the version is 2.7

Comment: is the python file being run in the same environment as these libraries ?